# ADFS change Audience attribute using claim rule?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

Is there a way to use a transform rule to change what is sent for the  field in a SAML 2.0 token using ADFS 4.0?

We have a RP Trust setup in ADFS with the identifier of 'https://SP1/app'.  The SAML token generated has the following (as expected).

`<AudienceRestriction>`
`<Audience>https://SP1/app</Audience>`
`</AudienceRestriction>`

We have a production and training environment we have to access with a vendor (there's a custom claim where we send over a unique code to identify the environment).  The problem is I cannot create a second Trust with the same identifier.  If I change the identifier it is rejected by the vendor (SP).  We have one ADFS farm, they have one SSO endpoint.

I was wondering if within ADFS I could setup another Trust, set the identifier to 'https://SP1/app1' then use a transform rule to modify the identifier to https://SP1/app' so that in the SAML token the Audience will be https://SP1/app (and NOT https://SP1/app1).

The SSO is initiated by the idP so the vendor doesn't support SP initiated SSO.

Thanks